# can not update fresh installed( SharePoint enterprise 2013 with SP1) farm with july-2020CU

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration

I've sharepoint 2013  farm with SP1 installed in win server R2 and there was error during sharepoint installation and  I edit 'Iglobal \ oserver.msi' with orca and it goes right and installed after that I try to install any update from april 2018 CU to Aug 2020 still gives me this error 'The expected version of the product was not found on the system '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start over. If you're having to edit an MSI for the installation, something went wrong.

Comment: I read  a lot of errors about installing sharepoint with sp1 on win server 2012 R2 ,should I use win 2012 instead

Comment: No, but in order to install 2012 R2 you need to use the SharePoint 2013 *with* SP1 ISO. You also need the 2012 R2 media handy for the .NET Framework install.